# Finite union of finite sets is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1, \dots A_n$ be finite sets. How can we show that the $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k$ ,union of finite dimensional sets, is finite?

Comment: In general, if $A,B$ are finite sets we have $|A\cup B|\leq |A|+|B|$, with equality if and only if $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Can you apply this, along with perhaps induction, to get your result?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow, Is it possible to show it by Proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yeah, but that would be overly complicated and not necessary for this problem.

Comment: finite dimensional or finite cardinalities?

Comment: @Koro finite dimensional

Comment: Finite dimensional does not make sense.

Comment: Finite cardinality instead of finite dimensional makes sense. Also, I have added a proof sketch.

Comment: There are different definitions of finite. Which one are you using? Dedekind finiteness?

Comment: @L.t. Which types of definitions of "finite" does exists?

Comment: @user40491 see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Necessary_and_sufficient_conditions_for_finiteness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right| \le \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|$$
If you want to show this, try a proof using induction. Since $|A_i| < \infty$ for every $i$, $\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| < \infty$. So, $\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right| < \infty$. The proof is complete.

This result is pretty intuitive, and here are some thoughts on a proof by contradiction. Suppose $\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right| = \infty$. If you delete finitely many elements from an infinite set, you still have infinite elements (you might ask for a proof of this too, but you need to start somewhere). Hence, by removing elements from the union which correspond to elements from the sets $A_i$ for $1\le i\le n$, you should still be left with infinite elements. However, the definition of union tells me that $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ if and only if $x \in A_i$ for some $i$ such that $1\le i\le n$. Contradiction!